# Yii2 dependency injection, configuration and inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, dependency-injection, yii2

Let's say I have a configuration like this (snippet from [official guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#application-configurations)):

```
$config = [
    // ...
    'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            'yii\widgets\LinkPager' => ['maxButtonCount' => 5],
        ],
    ],
    // ...
];
```

I create a class named FancyLinkPager:

```
class FancyLinkPager extends \yii\widgets\LinkPager
{
    // ...
}
```

When I create an object of class FancyLinkPager like so (please ignore the $pagination object, it's here for correctness sake):

```
$pagination     = \Yii::createObject(Pagination::class);
$linkPager      = \Yii::createObject(['class' => LinkPager::class, 'pagination' => $pagination]);
$fancyLinkPager = \Yii::createObject(['class' => FancyLinkPager::class, 'pagination' => $pagination]);
$linkPager->maxButtonCount; // 5 as configured
$fancyLinkPager->maxButtonCount; // 10 as LinkPager's default
```

My problem is that I wished $fancyLinkPager->maxButtonCount to be 5 as configured. I know I can add another line in the configuration or adjust it to specify my custom class, but it's not solution for me because:

1. I want to keep the code DRY
2. This is an oversimplified example of my needs - in real world you don't expect to have multiple LinkPager's child classes, but it is highly possible for other objects

**My question is: is there any framework-supported way of achieving this? The solutions I came up with are:**

1. Hack a custom __construct in FancyLinkPager (or another intermediate class or trait) so that it would look into App's configuration and call Yii::configure on the instance, but I don't find a good way to do it in generic way
2. Inject a dependency into FancyLinkPager with "setup" object, like LinkPagerSettings and configure that class in container section of my configuration, but it would make some trouble to work with vanilla LinkPager instances as well

Maybe the only real solution would be to create my own implementation of yii\di\Container that allows for inheriting configuration from parent classes but before I dive into this I would like to know if I haven't overlooked something.

Comment: Have the same problem: I think it is not possible to configure parent classes. Hence my configuration has some redundant settings... According to [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3940), overwriting Container may cause performance issues, since . I think your constructor approach is reasonable. Post an answer if your going to realize this.

Comment: Thank you @robsch for pointing me to Yii2's crew comment on this, I couldn't find it myself. It led me to understanding that it would best if configuration inheritance was optional and intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with my own implementation of DI container introducing new configurable property:

```
public $inheritableDefinitions = [];
```

Full class code:

```
<?php

namespace app\di;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
class Container extends \yii\di\Container
{
    /**
     * @var array inheritable object configurations indexed by class name
     */
    public $inheritableDefinitions = [];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @param array $params
     * @param array $config
     *
     * @return object the newly created instance of the specified class
     */
    protected function build($class, $params, $config) {
        $config = $this->mergeInheritedConfiguration($class, $config);

        return parent::build($class, $params, $config);
    }

    /**
     * Merges configuration arrays of parent classes into configuration of newly created instance of the specified class.
     * Properties defined in child class (via configuration or property declarations) will not get overridden.
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @param array $config
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function mergeInheritedConfiguration($class, $config) {
        if (empty($this->inheritableDefinitions)) {
            return $config;
        }

        $inheritedConfig = [];
        /** @var \ReflectionClass $reflection */
        list($reflection) = $this->getDependencies($class);

        foreach ($this->inheritableDefinitions as $parentClass => $parentConfig) {
            if ($class === $parentClass) {
                $inheritedConfig = array_merge($inheritedConfig, $parentConfig);
            } else if (is_subclass_of($class, $parentClass)) {
                /** @var \ReflectionClass $parentReflection */
                list($parentReflection) = $this->getDependencies($parentClass);

                // The "@" is necessary because of possible (and wanted) array to string conversions
                $notInheritableProperties = @array_diff_assoc($reflection->getDefaultProperties(),
                    $parentReflection->getDefaultProperties());

                // We don't want to override properties defined specifically in child class
                $parentConfig    = array_diff_key($parentConfig, $notInheritableProperties);
                $inheritedConfig = array_merge($inheritedConfig, $parentConfig);
            }
        }

        return array_merge($inheritedConfig, $config);
    }
}
```

This is how it can be used to accomplish customization of LinkPager described in the question:

```
'container'  => [
    'inheritableDefinitions' => [
        'yii\widgets\LinkPager'  => ['maxButtonCount' => 5],
    ],
],
```

Now if I create a class `FancyLinkPager` that extends `yii\widgets\LinkPager` the DI container will merge the default configuration:

```
$pagination     = \Yii::createObject(Pagination::class);
$linkPager      = \Yii::createObject(['class' => LinkPager::class, 'pagination' => $pagination]);
$fancyLinkPager = \Yii::createObject(['class' => FancyLinkPager::class, 'pagination' => $pagination]);
$linkPager->maxButtonCount; // 5 as configured
$fancyLinkPager->maxButtonCount; // 5 as configured - hurrah!
```

I have also taken into account [qiangxue's comment](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3940#issuecomment-46570136) about explicit setting of default property values in class definition, so if we declare the `FancyLinkPager` class as such:

```
class FancyLinkPager extends LinkPager
{
    public $maxButtonCount = 18;
}
```

the property setting will be respected:

```
$linkPager->maxButtonCount; // 5 as configured
$fancyLinkPager->maxButtonCount; // 18 as declared
```

To swap default DI container in your application you have to explicitly set `Yii::$container` somewhere in an entry script:

```
Yii::$container = new \app\di\Container();
```